# Submit custom form from post content and execute in plugin

Tags: plugins, forms, actions

I have prepared custom form (quiz plugin) with embedding in custom posts via {{QUIZ_ID}} placeholder. My form is displayed in post correctly but bigger problem is what form action should I create (and how to create that) to save all of data posted from this form to save in database (first) and display results (second) to user who submitted form?